# either post-infectious or not

Tags: word-usage

> On Feb 23, 2021, the National Institutes of Health announced a new US$1·15 billion initiative to support research and resources for so-called long COVID. This is the culmination of a year that has seen more scientific attention, public commentary, and media coverage of chronic unexplained medical symptoms (**either post-infectious or not**) than arguably the past decade combined. Indeed, one of the most concerning stories emerging out of the COVID-19 pandemic is the quandary of long COVID.

Source: [The Lancet  Long COVID has exposed medicine's blind-spot](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/laninf/article/PIIS1473-3099(21)00333-9/fulltext)

Does "either post-infectious or not" refer to "either post-infectious (symptoms) or not post-infectious (symptoms)"?
Why this thread? At the first glance of the phrase "either post-infectious or not", I thought "why not 'either post-infection or not'"? ("Why the adjective infectious rather than the noun infection." And then I realized it was because the adjective most likely modified the symptoms).

Answer (score 2):

It means unexplained medical symptoms that are preceded by an infection, or that are not preceded by an infection.
I agree that they should have used the noun "infection", not the adjective "infectious", as the object of the preposition "post".